# Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 setup failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have problems installing MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. because it is always says that **"ANOTHER INSTALLATION IS IN PROGRESS.PLEASE WAIT TO TRY AGAIN" AND "RETRYING MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ 2013 RUNTIME X64 ."** im stuck in that part.

please help me with my problem. I am a student please give me a clear and specific answer.

thank you.

Comment: It has been a well known issue of Windows Installer, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer so you should try to analyze which installation is in progress. It has nothing special to do with VS.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what should I do ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/55103/how-do-i-determine-what-the-windows-installer-msiexec-is-doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the Computer icon, wherever it exists on your system, and select Manage. (I’m using the Classic Start menu, so the Computer icon is on my desktop. If you’re using the new Start menu, the icon is in the Start menu.) This opens the Computer Management utility.

Select Services, right click on Windows Installer in the list and select Properties. If you’re having the problem, the Windows Installer service is started, and the Stop button is disabled. Simply rebooting doesn’t stop the service. Here’s how you stop it.

In the Properties dialog, change Startup type to “Disabled”, click OK, and reboot your computer. This stops the service. After your computer reboots, again open Computer Management (right-click on Computer and select Manage), open Windows Installer Properties, and change the Startup type back to Manual. Now you’re good to go and can start a new installation.

Comment: This worked for me with VS 2012 Professional.  The setup program ran again after the initial install though - just ended it.  Had the same problem installing SSMS.  Never had this issue before

Comment: I did not have to reboot. Stopping and Starting the service solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had launched the installer twice, by mistake.

So a quick fix was opening **`Task Manager > Processes`** and killing the two instances of **`msiexec.exe`** that were visible.

The next run was successful without issue.

For another list of solutions that helped others:

- [Visual Studio MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8734e43-d325-4b67-9843-ddbd4430e73a/another-installation-is-in-progress-please-wait-to-retry-again?forum=vssetup)
- [SQL Server MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7a3a40f2-d70a-4bd9-b477-735fd443b1e5/another-installation-is-in-progress-please-wait-to-try-again?forum=vssetup)
- [How To Solutions](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2015/08/solving-installation-is-stuck-problem-in-visual-studio-community-edition/#.VeirNVJm4hl)

Answer (score 1):

For me Windows Updates were waiting to install during next reboot. Try to reboot